# Navigate php menu to bootstrap

Tags: php, html

im new here and im still studying about php and bootstrap, for now im trying to use the col-sm-3 per category and its sub menu. i posted the code under and i having trouble because im new about his coding. can someone show me to convert its li to col-sm-3 so that i could have a good menu?

[this is my current menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4NAL.jpg)

and i want my menu becomes like this

[and this is what i want if someone help me :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TZRE.jpg)

```html
<ul class="main-navigation">
   
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category_1) { ?>
  <li>
   <a href="<?php echo $category_1['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></a>
      <?php if ($category_1['children']) { ?>
      <?php $i = count($category_1['children']); ?>
     
     <div class="categorybg">
       <div class="categoryinner">
             
        <ul>
        <?php $i=1; ?>
        <?php foreach ($category_1['children'] as $category_2) { ?>
       
        <li class="categorycolumn"><b><a class="submenu1" href="<?php echo $category_2['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></a></b>
        
          <?php if($category_2['children']) { ?>
         <?php $j = count($category_2['children']); ?>
         <?php if($j<=10) { ?>
         
         <div class="cate_inner_bg">
           <ul>
           <?php foreach ($category_2['children'] as $category_3) { ?>
           <li><a class="submenu2" href="<?php echo $category_3['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category_3['name']; ?></a></li>
           <?php } ?>
           </ul>
         </div>
        
         <?php } else { ?>
         
         <div>
           <ul>
           <?php $j=0; ?>
           <?php foreach ($category_2['children'] as $category_3) { ?>
           <li><a class="submenu2" href="<?php echo $category_3['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category_3['name']; ?></a></li>
           <?php if (++$j == 10) ?>
           <?php } ?>
           <li><a class="submenu2" href="<?php echo $category_2['href']; ?>">More....</a></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
         <?php } ?>
         
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
       
        <?php } ?>
        
        </ul>
        
     
  
       
      </div>
     </div>
    
    <?php } ?>
     <?php } ?>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at some template engines or something.. You've soo many `<?php ?>` in your code, that hurt my eyes D: Also there are some really useless ones... No need to do it on each line, simple open and close when you need to switch to HTML.

Comment: when i add category, it is automatically added to my menu, even it have submenu. thats why i'm trying to use this code instead of coding and html with bootstrap.